# Where can I find the new Layout Inspector from Android Studio 2.2 Preview 1

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

Just wondering where I can find the new Layout Inspector feature in Android Studio 2.2 released yesterday.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find the new Layout Inspector in the Android Monitor section at the bottom of your new Android studio Window. There you can pick the button just below the screen recording

Comment: I'm trying it out and it's showing the screenshot but it stopped showing the view hierarchy info: (see http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/05/android-studio-22-preview-new-ui.html all the stuff on the left and right). Any idea how to get that back?

Comment: Same problem, it must be a bug, haven't been able to find a way to get it back yet..

Comment: That's a bug. The panels are there but with 1 px of width. Try to drag them carefully to show them back. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=210440&q=Layout%20Inspector&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened

Answer (score 12):

Android Monitor has been replaced by Android profiler which no longer contains Layout Inflator...It has been moved to..
**Tools -> Android -> Layout Inspector...**

Check the below image:

[image: Layout Inflator in Android Studio 3.0]

Comment: In my case the button is disabled, I don't know why. Can you help?

Comment: @AnasAzeem: Check in android studio menu: **Tools -> Android -> Layout Inspector**

Answer (score 1):

**Android Studio 3.0 onwards**,  Android Monitor is replaced by Android Profiler, which does **not** have Layout Inspector.
You can find it:

[image]

Comment: Android Studio 3.0 onward also have layout inspector. You can find it in Tools -> Layout Inspector

Answer (score 1):

None of the above worked in android 4. I've found that it has been moved to `View` / `Tool Windows`/ `Layout Inspector`

[image: Layout Inspector]

[Animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrYRs.gif)